# relationships and association_proxy in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, relationship

We're using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy for a service (latest versions).  We have a 'static' table that is prepopulated with data and shouldn't be inserted into.  Very basic schema of varchar id and name.

We have another table that has two fields that reference that table, for a list of ids, and a list of objects.  There's essentially a many-to-many relationship, though the 'static' table doesn't know about the dynamic table.  I created a mapping table to support that.

Here's the model objects (simplified):

```
a_to_type_mapping = Table(
    "a_to_type_mapping",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("a_id", ForeignKey("a.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("type_id", ForeignKey("type.id"), primary_key=True),
)
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, index=True, primary_key=True)
    types: Mapped[List["Type"]] = relationship(lazy="selectin", secondary=a_to_type_mapping)
    type_ids: AssociationProxy[List[str]] = association_proxy("types","id")

class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = "type"
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(index=True, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, nullable=False)
```

This seems to work fine except when I hit parts of my pytests where I'm inserting a new object, like:

```
A(
    id="SomeId"
    types=[Type(id="2",name="Two")]
)
```

Basically trying to say the new A is associated with that Type.  But during the test, it's trying to insert Type id=2 into the 'type' table and of course hitting a unique contraint error (Type(id="2", name="Two") was previously inserted as setup)

Would this not be the correct way to realize this sort of relationship?  Essentially I want the Type table to be read only, but still allow new A objects to be created and reference that table (both in a list of ids and a list of associated objects).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your test actually looks like but you should fetch the type first.  Another option if you have a static table is to populate it with a fixture that you import during a test.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

def test_create_a(db_session):
    type_2 = db_session.scalars(select(Type).where(id="2")).first()
    a = A(
        id="SomeId"
        types=[type2]
    )
    db_session.add(a)
    db_session.flush()
```

Comment: Ah that did it.  Instead of building new Type objects in A when doing all my session.adds, I used the initial Type references (when doing setup).  And then where I'm adding a new A into the db I did
```
    stmt = (
                    select(Type)
                    .filter(Type.id == "2")
      )
     type_2 = await transaction_session.scalar(stmt)
```
and stuck type_2 into the new A.  Thanks!!